# Launch screen for iOS

Tags: ios, launch-screen

I have read a few posts on this topic about making the launch screen last longer, but I want to make it shorter.

Currently my launch screen takes 4 seconds before loading the login screen, and the app is not even close to being finished yet. Does that mean the launch screen could take longer to load once the app is finished?

Is there any way to make the launch screen appear for 2 seconds?

Xcode, Swift. backend in PHP.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What research have you done? Please add more information so people do not duplicate work you have already done.

Comment: I've read a lot about this, but all the forum posts on this topic are about making the splash screen longer. I want to make mine shorter, I've been told I have no control over this, I know there are work arounds for making it longer such as sleep scripts, but I have found nothing on making the launcher screen shorter... its currently 4 seconds and I want to make it 2 seconds.

Comment: It appears until your app finished loading. Update your question with details about what your app does on startup.

Comment: Ok.. perhaps then its taking 4 seconds because the app is still in development? On startup the launcher screen appears straight away and after 4 seconds loads the first screen of the app. I am using hexcode for the background colour of the launcher screen and a .pdf file for the resource on the screen, would it be better practice to consolidate the launcher screen into a .png image? would this help reduce the time of the launcher screen delay?

Comment: As I said, update your question with the code you a running on app launch. Show your relevant app delegate code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The launch screen loading time depends on how "long" it takes your initial view controller to be prepared.

So, if you want it to "load faster" make your initial view controller more lightweight, do this by:

- Reducing the number of interface elements being shown
- Do not perform that many operations inside the "view did load" method.

Other than this, theres really not much you can do to control the time.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't really a straightforward way of making the launch screen last shorter, because it depends on how long it takes for the necessities of your app to load.

Remember, the shorter the launch screen, the better, so the users of your app won't think that your app is taking a lot of time to boot up.